# Location tracking stops when using back button in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a `UISwitch` which is used to track location in background services using `navigation controller`. If i come out my app it works well but when i switch on the button and moved back to `main window` the location tracking stops.

I used the following the code,

```
-(IBAction)startTracking:(id)sender{
if(startTrackingButton.on){
   [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];}
else{
   [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
 [super viewDidLoad];
 locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
 [locationManager setDelegate:self];
 [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];}
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Track the location in a singleton object.... or may be even in app delegate .... in your case definitely it shouldn't be in view controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because your locationManager (aswell as your UISwitch and UIViewController) object is being deallocated when you pop back on the Navigation stack.

To confirm this add this method to your viewController with the switch.

```
- (void) dealloc 
{

  NSLog(@"Object being destroyed");
}
```

If "Object being destroyed" prints when you move back to the 'main view' then you know what the problem is.

To resolve this, have your UIViewController with the switch be a property of the main UIViewController, this way the object will be created once for the lifetime of your application and you can pop and push it as required.

You should also wrap your pushViewController code in something like this, create a property to store you switchViewController **pseudocode**:

```
if(self.switchViewController)
{
    NSLog(@"switchViewController Already Created");
    [navigationController pushViewController:self.switchViewController];
}
else 
{
    self.switchViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [navigationController pushViewController:switchViewController];
}
```

If you don't check that the switchViewController property is already instantiated you would end up creating a new instance each time.

John

Comment: yes your are right, i get this when i dealloc `Object being destroyed<UISwitch: 0x749cba0; frame = (219 69; 79 27); opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x74a0d00>>`

Comment: Good, do you understand the solution I outlined above? ie. make your switchViewController a property of your mainViewController and check if it's created before alloc initing it?

Comment: ya i understood it but i have only one View controller. how can i set property here?

Comment: You must have two viewControllers, one main View (that you move back to - which your app loads when it starts) and one switchView that you move forward to? Is that not the case?

Comment: i have a `main window` which provided default in story board and another `switch window` which holds my switch. when i click button in window it moves to the `switch window`

Comment: In the file where you invoke showing the switch window (so the action method of clicking a button or selecting a cell from a table view), create a property (@property (nonatomic, strong) SWitchViewController *switchViewController) to store switchViewController, then do the check as @JohnWoods as suggested. This will prevent your switchViewController from being deallocated when clicking the back button.

Comment: When i tried with the above the code, its not entering into `if` statement always it executes `else`